# How to install class derived from TeeChart?

Tags: teechart

We have created a visual component class that is derived from TeeChart classes.  When I include this new class in my DclUser package, I get a warning that unit TeeProCo is now in both the DclUser package and in the TeeChart packages.  This causes TeeChart to stop loading.

Is there a way to create a derived class which avoids this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that some of the TeeChart units that were in the Uses statement were, in fact, not required for the compilation of the class at all. Once I removed those units, the problems were resolved.